# Experience Manager update preview is not working

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

Experience Manager update preview is not working.
I am getting popup on right hand side which says.

> "The preview for this page is not up to date
>   Your changes to this page make an update of the page preview necessary"

I checked the log files for error. I have this error in `cd_core` log file.

> ERROR ODataWebserviceHandler - Error reading configuration 'cd_webservice_conf.xml', using Tridion defaults.
>   com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find configuration file: [ cd_webservice_conf.xml ]
>       at com.tridion.configuration.XMLConfigurationReader.readConfiguration(XMLConfigurationReader.java:64) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.init(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:73) [cd_odata.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:63) [cd_odata.jar:na]

Please provide your inputs to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very clear from the following exception that your `cd_webservice_conf` is having some error. First verify it does not have any XML error than compare your config with [kickstart](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/kickstart-tridion-environment/tree/master/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/ConfigSamples/preview-webservice) from Nuno

> Error reading configuration 'cd_webservice_conf.xml', using Tridion defaults. com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find configuration file: [ cd_webservice_conf.xml ]

Comment: Hi Raj Kumar thanks for your response. Is the `cd_webservice_conf.xml` file necessary for experience manager web service ?

Comment: Yes it's very much required, see the link which I mentioned in the answer. also go back one level on the link also check config in `preview-web` folder.